# How to check for java.lang.AssertionError (JUnit 5)

Tags: java, junit, junit5

Suppose the following class

```
class classToTest{
  public static void methodToTest() {
    assert false: "error is thrown";
  }
}
```

Is it possible to check with JUnit 5 if the `methodToTest()` throws the error evoked by the assert statement?

I only found in the JUnit 5 doc the `assertThrows`, but it checks only for exceptions and not for errors.

> Asserts that execution of the supplied executable throws an exception of the expectedType and returns the exception.

How would a test case look like to check weather the error is thrown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, with `assertThrows` you can check for *all* `Throwable` like Exception, RuntimeException and Error. The `assert` keyword throws an AssertionError, which is a Throwable.

```
AssertionError error = Assertions.assertThrows(AssertionError.class, () -> {
    classToTest.methodToTest();
});
Assertions.assertEquals("error is thrown", error.getMessage());
```